# Hover action gets inverted after click event at jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-hover, jquery-click-event

I am using a system to highlight 2 columns when the cursor is over one of them.

Then, the user can change the value from `No` to `Yes` inside each cell by clicking on it.
When this happens, the `hover` action seems to works inverted. It acts when the cursor is outside instead.

Here is the fiddle with my example:
http://jsfiddle.net/L9Kfq/

The columns should keep being highlight when i click to change the value of a cell.
Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplified your jQuery a little bit, and used `mouseover` and `mouseout` instead of `hover`. I hope the code segment that follows is self-explanatory.

```
$('td,th').on('mouseover', function() {
    $('td:not(.'+$(this).attr('class')+')').addClass('active');
    $('td.'+$(this).attr('class')).removeClass('active');
});

$('td,th').on('mouseout', function() {
    $('td').removeClass('active');
});
```

Also see updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9Kfq/4/).